# Does srand(getpid()) affect format / structure?

Tags: c, unix, srand

This question's a quick one :). I know `srand()` is used to seed a random number generator in order to prevent the same sequence of random numbers being generated. Similarly, I know that `getpid()` "shall return the process ID of the calling process."

( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpid.html )

Due to the process ID ultimately being different each time you run my program (a program that where a producer and consumer communicate over shared memory), the PID will also be different, thus giving a perfect seed. I've set a range for the random numbers `rand() % (100-1) + 1`.

Does `srand(getpid())` deliver random numbers in a specific format?

For completeness, here is the section of code my enquiry relates to:

```
srand(getpid());

while(x == 0)
{      
        if(*randNum == 101)
        {      
                *randNum = rand() % (100 - 1) + 1;
                *pidNum = getpid();

                printf("priority: %d Process ID: %d \n", *randNum, *pidNum);

                x = 1;
        }   
        else
        {      
                *randNum++;
                *pidNum++;
        }   
}
```

Comment: What would be a "format" of random numbers for you?

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by a specific format.  But getpid() is not a good choice a s a seed.  PIDs are in a pretty small range of the "unsigned" space and are trivial to guess.

If you do not care about people being able to guess your seed, time(NULL) is a much better choice as a seed.

Comment: except when it's possible that two processes run at the same time. I think it's difficult to find a 'generally good' seed (but of course you're right about using getpid())

Comment: `srand(time(NULL) ^ getpid())` is one approach, but if you care that much about unpredictability and/or high-quality pseudo-random numbers, you should probably be using something other than `srand` and `rand`.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt it's perfectly trivial to get a 'generally good' seed. Read `sizeof(int)` bytes from `/dev/urandom` (or `/dev/random` if you are so inclined) on a Linux system. Other operating systems offer similar facilities. On Windows [`CryptGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx) will work very well (or [`RtlGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387694(v=vs.85).aspx) if you're feeling a little more adventurous and are averse to opening a cryptographic provider).

Comment: @Nik thanx, I didn't think abount that

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys :). My question regarding format was more how it would look in output. The reason I haven't been able to test this was due to me continuously getting "Segmentation Faults" and not having had time to debug it properly.

Since the output is a priority list simulating print jobs (processes created by the producer attached to a random number detailing the print job 'name / id') I just wanted to clear up whether they would look like PID values or not and now I understand. 

Thanks again!

Comment: `time` is much worse than `getpid`; not only is it more predictable; it will actually repeat for tens or even hundreds of runs if you invoke the program rapidly. The **only** things you should be using as a random seed are either the `tv_nsec` field of `struct timespec` returned by `clock_gettime` or bytes from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @R.  time is not more predictable than getpid..  On most systems, there is only 32K possible values for the PID.  You can find the pid by just running ps or looking at /proc.  Your point about clock_gettime is interesting but the seed is just an unsigned and most system clock do not have nsecs resolution so it's probably not a good idea.
Reading from /dev/urandom is def better.  I just gave an example of easy one that's better than getpid but I clearly said that it was easy to guess.

Answer (score 0):

No two running processes ever have the same PID, that's for sure, but there is no guarantee that a new process does not get the same PID as a process that just terminated. Usually the PID is constantly increased, but it will overflow sooner or later (e.g. on Linux the maximum PID is 32'768 by default) and then PIDs that were already used before will get recycled (some systems also recycle earlier than that, e.g. as they have reserved PID ranges for different kind of processes and so on).

The next issue is `rand` is a **very bad random generator** on many systems out there (Linux may be an exception, but your tags say "UNIX"). BSD even states that literary on the man page (true for most descendants of BSD, even including MacOS X). It is only there for compatibility with non-POSIX code. All modern code uses [`random`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/random.html) instead. It is a much better random number generator on most systems (and on the other systems, it is also not worse than `rand()`, so you have nothing to lose using it). Unless you can always tell for sure that your code will never run on any system with a "weak `rand()`" implementation, using `random` is the safe approach.

Most systems support a call `srandomdev()`, which is not part of the POSIX standard, yet it is almost available on all systems nowadays. This initializes `random` by reading data from a random generator in the system kernel (on many systems available through `/dev/random`). This random number generator generates very good random numbers and depending on the system hardware, it can even generate "real random numbers". E.g. many modern CPUs and some mainboard chips have hardware random number generators that can produce random numbers out of some kind of "random electrical noise", which are almost perfectly random - if such a hardware is available and the kernel supports it, it will use it for generating the random numbers.

Comment: On Linux, `rand` is, since who-knows-when, the same as `random`. While it's a good reason to prefer `random` if your code may have to run on a platform with bad `rand`, unconditionally saying that `rand` is very bad isn't right.

Comment: `rand` shouldn't be the same as `random`, for the very simply reason, that there exists software, that relies on the broken behavior of `rand`. Consider an application working over network, one copy runs on Linux, the other one on BSD. If both call `srand()` with the same seed, they should produce the same random numbers (this is expected and desired behavior), yet if Linux has really changed `rand` to work like `random`, this software would break. That's why `rand` was not changed by most systems, but a new function `random` has been introduced.

Comment: @Mecki: The behavior of `rand` is implementation-specific. You cannot rely on the same seed producing the same sequence except on the same implementation. If you want this kind of guarantee, write your own function similar to `rand`. The traditional `rand` is 1 line of C and you can just copy and paste it out of the C standard, but many implementations use slightly-less-bad versions you may prefer to copy.

Comment: The standard doesn't say how `rand` should behave (beyond that it produces pseudo-random numbers in the range from 0 to `RAND_MAX`), so relying on anything about its behaviour is completely broken. `RAND_MAX` already changes between implementations.

Comment: By the way, making a *statistically strong* (which is not the same as cryptographically strong) PRNG is very simple. I experimented with it a while back and found that even a 32-bit LCG with a tempering function applied to the output passed all statistical tests I could throw at it except ones that caught the short period 2^32. If you apply that same tempering function to the upper 32 bits of a 64-bit LCG, you should have a (statistically) very strong, and very fast, PRNG.

Comment: Okay, fine, `rand` may not be a bad random number generator on all systems, but it is on all BSD based systems, including Mac OS X, and if you want to write POSIX code that needs good random numbers, you simply don't use `rand`, as you can never say for sure, that your code is not running on a system, where `rand` is a bad one. `random` is a good one on all systems known.

Comment: @Mecki: `random` is also thread-safe, whereas `rand` is not, but the state for `random` is shared by all threads, so you cannot get reproducible results if multiple threads are using it (which one takes the next value in the sequence first will depend on scheduling). Also, using `random` in libraries is not appropriate since it will interfere with the calling program's state/sequence. For these reasons, many projects are stuck using `rand_r`, which has *even worse* quality than `rand`, and can't be much improved...

Comment: @R.. See POSIX man page for random: *"Threaded applications should use erand48(), nrand48(), or jrand48() instead of random() when an independent random number sequence in multiple threads is required."* These functions get their state as input parameter, thus every thread/library can have their own state.

Comment: @Mecki: Indeed, but those functions are in the XSI (Unix) option, not POSIX base, and their API is complicated (and their strength weakened) by being based on an array of shorts rather than simple 64-bit arithmetic. The trivial one-liner `return (seed = 6364136223846793005ULL*seed + 1) >> 33;` (where `seed` is `uint64_t`) is a better PRNG than those functions.